Fatal error: Index out of range when adding and removing from Array with MVVM
I'm trying to display an array of Word structs, in child TextFields, using MVVM architecture by passing in a binding to the Word structure to the child. There is a button to insert a new, blank, Word into the array at position 0, which populates through the ForEach loop into the child elements. However, if the textfield is left blank and the focus changes, I would like to remove this item from the parent array. I have passed through the function to do this in the parent ForEach loop. Finally, in the OnChange modifier in the child I call this function if the oldValue is equal the one that lost focus and isEmpty is true.  But this results in a Fatal error: Index out of range.
In debugging, it seems that the code successfully removed the desired item from the array, and that the error comes from subsequent passes of the ForEach loop through the words array. How can I fix this? All of my code is below.
The parent code
struct Word: Identifiable, Equatable {
    var id: String
    var word: String
    var definition: String?
    
    init(_ word: String, definition: String?) {
        self.word = word
        self.definition = definition
        self.id = UUID().uuidString
    }
    
    static func ==(lhs: Word, rhs: Word) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
}

class CardModel: ObservableObject {
    
    var word: Binding<Word>
    @Published var loading: Bool = false
    
    init(word: Binding<Word>) {
        self.word = word
    }
    
}

enum Focusable: Hashable {
  case none
  case row(id: String)
}

struct CardView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var model: CardViewModel
    
    @FocusState var focused: Focusable?

    let onEmpty: () -> Void // delete the word!
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            HStack { TextField("", text: model.word.word)
                    .font(.title)
                    .focused($focused, equals: .row(id: model.word.id))
                
                ; Spacer() }
            
            if model.loading == true {
                Text("Loading...")
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            }
            
            if let definition = vm.word.definition.wrappedValue {
                Text(definition)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            }

         }
        .onChange(of: focused) { oldValue, newValue in
            
            if oldValue == .row(id: model.word.wrappedValue.id) && model.word.wrappedValue.word.isEmpty {
                onEmpty()
            }
        }
        
    }
}

The child code
import SwiftUI

class StudyModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var words: [Word] =
    [
        Word("sonder", definition: "The realization that each passerby has a life as vivid as your own."), 
        [...]
    ]
    
}

struct StudyView: View {
    
    @Namespace private var namespace
    
    @State private var cardsHeight: CGFloat = 0
    
    @FocusState var focusedReminder: Focusable?
    
    @StateObject var model: StudyModel = StudyModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "gear")
                    Spacer()
                    Button {
                        // add action here
                        addWordCard()
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
                    }
                    .tint(.black)


            }
            .font(.title)
                ScrollView {
                VStack(spacing: 20) {
                    ForEach($model.words) { $word in
                        CardView(vm: CardModel(word: $word), focused: _focusedReminder) {
                            deleteWord($word.wrappedValue)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
}

// Helper Functions
extension StudyView {
    
    private func addWordCard() {
        withAnimation(.spring) {
            let new_word = Word("", definition: nil)
            model.words.insert(new_word, at: 0)
            focusedReminder = .row(id: new_word.id)
        }
    }
    
    private func deleteWord(_ word: Word) {
        withAnimation(.spring) {

//            model.words.removeAll { $0.id == word.id }
        }
    }
}


Remove the view models and replace them with @State properties instead for word, words etc

Is there a reason you're using @ObservedObject instead of @Binding? Does your app need to target an old iOS version?

Also, what's the intention for the textfield? Is it to add a new word along with a new definition or is it meant to act more as a search field for selecting one of the existing words?

Get rid of the Equatable implementation and don’t use Binding in a class

The way you go about some of the logic raises many questions for me, so below is an example of how I would go about it, with some considerable changes that seek to streamline everything.
Here are some comments about aspects of your code.
Inserting a blank word at position 0
There are two main issues here. First, why even insert a blank word at all? If the textfield is blank, nothing should happen. Second, if a word is inserted, there is no need to insert it at a certain position. You could simply append it to the array. If your goal is to show the newly added word at the top, then there should be a sorting mechanism, like a timestamp property that would allow you to sort by it. The example code below uses a createdAt property to this effect.
Use of @ObservedObject
Unless you have a specific need for it, you should use @Observable macro, which simplifies things considerably. The example code below uses it.
Using descriptive naming
As per the Swift language guidelines, you should name parameters in a way that describes them and allows others to easily understand their purpose. So parameters like vm, don't quite adhere to this convention.
Deleting from the model array using Comparable
The primary reason for your crash is probably the fact that you're deleting an object from the array that is being iterated on. To fix this, you need to remove the word from the array outside of the iteration context or remove the element directly by its index, to ensure that the mutation happens in a controlled way.
Using Binding in a class
As others have pointed out in comments, this is not a good practice. You can get a binding using @Bindable when using @Observable, as shown in the example code.
Buttons should be in a toolbar
This should be pretty obvious, but buttons for adding a word and accessing settings should be in a toolbar, normally.

Code

Click the + button to show the input field to add a word.
Press Enter to submit the textfield and add the word.
Pressing Enter if textfield is empty does nothing (as it should), other than hiding the input field.
Tapping any existing card allows for the editing of the word definition.
Words can be deleted by tapping a card to edit and then the trash can icon.

So give this a try and let me know if it makes sense.
import SwiftUI

//Word struct
struct Word: Identifiable, Equatable {
    
    //Properties
    let id = UUID()
    var word: String
    var definition: String
    var createdAt: Date
    
    //Initializer
    init(_ word: String, definition: String = "", createdAt: Date = Date()) {
        self.word = word
        self.definition = definition
        self.createdAt = createdAt
    }
    
}

//Main view
struct StudyView: View {
    
    //Form states
    @State private var showInput: Bool = false
    @State private var inputText: String = ""
    
    //Bindings
    @Bindable var studyCardWords: StudyCardWords = StudyCardWords()
    
    //Focus states
    @FocusState private var focused: Bool
    
    //Body
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            
            //Input field
            if showInput {
                HStack {
                    TextField("Add word...", text: $inputText)
                        .font(.title2)
                        .textInputAutocapitalization(.never)
                        .padding(10)
                        .focused($focused)
                        .background {
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16)
                                .stroke(.gray.opacity(0.2))
                        }
                        .onSubmit {
                            withAnimation {
                                //Add word
                                if !inputText.isEmpty {
                                    let newWord = Word(inputText)
                                    studyCardWords.words.append(newWord)
                                }
                                
                                //Clear the field
                                inputText = ""
                                
                                //Optional - hide input on submit
                                showInput = false
                            }
                        }
                }
                .padding()
            }
                
            //Words list
            ScrollView {
                VStack(spacing: 20) {
                    ForEach($studyCardWords.words.sorted { $0.wrappedValue.createdAt > $1.wrappedValue.createdAt } ) { $word in
                        StudyCardView(word: $word, deleteAction: {
                            
                            //Delete by index to prevent crashing
                            if let index = studyCardWords.words.firstIndex(where: { $0 == word }) {
                                studyCardWords.words.remove(at: index)
                            }
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
            .padding()
            
            //MARK: - Toolbar
            
            .navigationTitle("Study Cards")
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .primaryAction) {
                    Button {
                        withAnimation {
                            showInput.toggle()
                            focused = true
                        }
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
                    }
                }
                
                ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarLeading) {
                    Button {
                        //action here...
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "gear")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
}

//StudyCardView
struct StudyCardView: View {
    
    //Parameters
    @Binding var word: Word
    var deleteAction: () -> Void
    
    //Form states
    @State private var showInput: Bool = false
    // @State private var inputDefinition: String = ""
    
    //Focus states
    @FocusState private var focused: Bool
    
    //Body
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
            
            //Word
            HStack {
                Text(word.word)
                    .font(.title)
                
                Spacer()
                
                //Show an attention-grabbing icon if no definition
                if word.definition.isEmpty, !showInput {
                    Image(systemName: "brain.filled.head.profile")
                        .foregroundStyle(.secondary)
                        // .padding()
                }
                
                //Show delete button when editing definition
                else if showInput {
                    Button {
                        withAnimation {
                            deleteAction()
                        }
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "trash")
                    }
                    .tint(.red)
                }
            }
            
            //Definition input
            if showInput {
                TextField("Definition", text: $word.definition, axis: .vertical)
                    .padding(10)
                    .background(.white, in: RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16))
                    .padding(.top, 5)
                    .focused($focused)
                    .onSubmit {
                        withAnimation {
                            showInput = false
                            focused = false
                        }
                    }
            }
            
            //Show the definition
            else {
                if !word.definition.isEmpty {
                    Text(word.definition)
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
        .background(word.definition.isEmpty ? .yellow.opacity(0.5) : .gray.opacity(0.1), in: RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
        .overlay(alignment: .trailing) {
            
        }
        
        //Card tap action
        .onTapGesture {
            withAnimation {
                
                //Show definition input field
                showInput.toggle()
                focused = true
            }
        }
    }
}

//Observable model
@Observable
class StudyCardWords {
    
    //Properties
    var words: [Word] =
    [
        Word("erudite", definition: "Having or showing great knowledge or learning."),
        Word("efficient", definition: "Achieving maximum productivity with minimum wasted effort or expense."),
        Word("sonder", definition: "The realization that each passerby has a life as vivid as your own."),
        // [...]
    ]
    
}

//Preview
#Preview {
    StudyView()
}


